# Allowing "regular" users access to Sonata Admin CRUD actions

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

hope someone can steer me in the right direction!

I'm setting up a SonataAdmin based system for a project I'm working on that utilizes the SonataUserBundle.

I have a model setup extending AbstractMain for CRUD actions which is accessible using the navigation menu. From here, as a super admin, I can list, create, edit and delete items.  Perfect!

My aim is to use the same SonataAdmin portal for 'subscribed' users, but with limited access.  They should only be able to list items.  However, I'm at something of a loss when it comes to just how to configure the symfony / sonata / fosuser security & firewall rules going on under the hood to make this happen.

My app/config/security.yml is as such.

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
#            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    acl:
        provider: mongodb_acl_provider

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        hwi:
            id: sonata_oauth2_login.user.provider

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
#            #pattern: /admin(.*) #REMOVE THIS LINE IF YOU ARE USING SONATA ADMIN
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /portal/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /portal/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /portal/dashboard
            logout:
                path:           /portal/logout
                target:         /portal/login
            anonymous:          true
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    google:         "/login/check-google"
                    facebook:       "/login/check-facebook"
                login_path:        /portal/login                 # For Sonata Admin
                use_forward:       false
                default_target_path: /portal/dashboard           # For Sonata Admin
                failure_path:      /portal/login                 # For Sonata Admin
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service:  sonata_oauth2_login.user.provider

    access_control:
        # Admin login page needs to be accessed without credential
        - { path: ^/portal/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/portal/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/portal/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/portal/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/portal/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_USER] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
services:
    mongodb_acl_provider:
        parent: doctrine_mongodb.odm.security.acl.provider
```

This is my sonata_admin config under config.yml:

```
sonata_admin:
    title: BLAHBLAH
    options:
        title_mode: single_text

    templates:
        list: AppBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        base_list_field: AppBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
        layout: AppBundle::standard_layout.html.twig

    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl
#        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role

        role_admin: ROLE_ADMIN
        role_super_admin: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

        # acl security information
        information:
            GUEST:    [VIEW, LIST]
            STAFF:    [EDIT, LIST, CREATE]
            EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]

        # permissions not related to an object instance and also to be available when objects do not exist
        # the DELETE admin permission means the user is allowed to batch delete objects
        admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]

        # permission related to the objects
        object_permissions: [VIEW, EDIT, DELETE, UNDELETE, OPERATOR, MASTER, OWNER]
```

Now, with this configuration, I can (as a superadmin) edit a user and grant the individual user through the ACL settings access to edit their own profile, as seen here:

[ACL Settings for user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uhu7.png)

Nothing exists in the user settings for roles...

[Roles for user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XkMO.png)

I've done what I can to follow along with the SonataUserBundle instructions for setting up security, but I'm falling short in understanding somewhere along the way.

In short, all users will be utilizing the same admin portal.  Admins can create new users, products, etc.  "Regular" users can edit their own profile and 'view' products from the admin class extended from AbstractAdmin by clicking the link in the menu on the left.

I feel like I'm wandering around Symfony security blindfolded right now with fosuserbundle & sonatauserbundle added to the mix. :(

This is my first post, so please forgive me if I'm missing anything important to include. I'll do my best to fill in any details and I appreciate your time observing my plight!